# wp get image editor not saving image

Tags: php, wordpress, image

wp_get_image_editor() resize and save images fine on localhost(mamp) but on the server its simply not working(saving) no error, Here is my code

```
function image_crop($url, $name){ 

  $image = wp_get_image_editor( $url );

  if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {

    $image->resize( 100, 140, true );

    $data = $image->save( $name.'_'.$id.'.png' );

  }

  if( ! is_wp_error( $data )  )
  {

      return "ok";

  }else{

      return "Error";

  }

}
```

this function returns "ok" but on destination directory is empty, no images.

Comment: that might be due to your folder permission. chek your folder permission

Comment: this folder got 777 permission

Comment: check you server side support via the widely available GD and/or ImageMagick libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save a picture using the tool wp_get_image editor, you must do the following:

```
// load image object
// the best way to use picture path instead of url, as in the example below
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/image.png' );

// process image
if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
    $image->resize( 100, 140, true );

    // save the root site irectory called new_image.png
    // use path to the folder where you want to save a picture
    $image->save( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/new_image.png' );
}
```

The folder into which you keep the picture must have permission to record, such as 755 or 777.